# Hide Add to Cart button in Woocommerce product variations for a specific attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to hide add to cart button for variations with a specific selected value for one of attributes. There are two attributes for each variation (`pa_color` and `pa_size`)
For example for a variable product, we have these options:

1) `Red - XL`
2) `Red - XXL`
3) `Blue - M`
4) `Blue - XL`

I want to hide add to cart button for `XL` so users could not add options having XL to cart (1 and 4 in this example)

P.S:
We don't want to disable the variation, so variation image could show up by selecting this option, So deactivating the variation or removing the price and.. isn't the solution for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to make **add to cart button inactive** on product variations which product attribute **"pa_size"** with a **"XL"** value:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'conditional_variation_is_purchasable', 20, 2 );
function conditional_variation_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {

    ## ---- Your settings ---- ##

    $taxonomy  = 'pa_size';
    $term_name =  'XL';

    ## ---- The active code ---- ##

    $found = false;

    // Loop through all product attributes in the variation
    foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
        $attribute_taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $variation_attribute); // The taxonomy
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy ); // The WP_Term object
        // Searching for attribute 'pa_size' with value 'XL'
        if($attribute_taxonomy == $taxonomy && $term->name == $term_name ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $found )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't seem to get this to work with my custom attributes or attributes with text only. It works perfectly with attributes with numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Use your slug text for term_name

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'conditional_variation_is_purchasable', 20, 2 );
function conditional_variation_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {

    ## ---- Your settings ---- ##

    $taxonomy  = 'pa_size';
    $term_name =  'XL';

    ## ---- The active code ---- ##

    $found = false;

    // Loop through all product attributes in the variation
    foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
        $attribute_taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $variation_attribute); // The taxonomy
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy ); // The WP_Term object
        // Searching for attribute 'pa_size' with value 'XL'
        if($attribute_taxonomy == $taxonomy && $term->slug == $term_name ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $found )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```