# WooCommerce hide add to cart for specific product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want the Add to Cart function in WooCommerce to be completely hidden for specific production variations. I have a product offer (request a quote) plugin which in some cases I want to be used.

For example, a t-shirt in xl and green should be possible to be bought, but if there needs to be a print on it (I got variations for a print in 1, 2 or 3 colors), I want people to use the "request an offer button". So to hide the add to cart button would be great.

I saw the next post, however this one still shows the add to cart button (and doesn't seem to work for me)

[Hide Add to Cart button in Woocommerce product variations for a specific attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515176/hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-product-variations-for-a-specific-attribu)

Comment: Not possible… Or you use pure custom code, or you use plugins. Because most plugins are not maid to be customized (they are not open).

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I got some sort of workaround, I’ve set stock on 0 for these product variations. Changed the out of stock text. The add to cart is not oressible and customer now he only can request an offer. Next step would be to make the add to cart button invisble, if stock is 0, i hope that is possible.