# Hide Add-to-cart-button for specific attribut value or Variations

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I search a solution to hide add to cart button for variations with a specific selected value for one of attributes.
We have two types of variations (Offene Schulung and Individuelle Schulung) for all our products.
And we show the add to cart button and an "Request a Quote" Button - coming from Yithemes "Request a Quote" plugin.
Problem was that only for the first variation (Offene Schulung) should show both Buttons. For the Individuelle Schulung should only the request a quote Button shown.

I found the solution to hide a button related to attribute value over purchasable: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515176/hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-product-variations-for-a-specific-attribu)

These hides perfectly the button, but it means that my used Plugin YiThemes request a quote think's that the variation is not purchasable and creates an empty offer.

So my idea was to add around the add to cart Button a specific ID or CSS class related to the attribute value. With these i could hide the button with an css "display:none".

But till yet if found no method to do that.

Taxonomy was 'pa_trainingsart' and the term_name was 'Individuelle Schulung'.

Try to use a lot of scripts and functions.php samples form StackOverflow, but till yet without any results