# Disable users from adding to cart if a specific attribute is selected

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I want to prevent users from adding to cart if a specific attribute is selected.

The attribute name is "Production Time" and the specific value we want to disable from purchasing is "Urgent".

The code below is from this link - [Hide Add to Cart button in Woocommerce product variations for a specific attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515176/hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-product-variations-for-a-specific-attribu)

However, it only works with numbers. When the attribute is a text, it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'conditional_variation_is_purchasable', 20, 2 );

function conditional_variation_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {

    ## ---- Your settings ---- ##

    $taxonomy  = 'production-time';
    $term_name =  'urgent';

    ## ---- The active code ---- ##

    $found = false;

    // Loop through all product attributes in the variation
    foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
        $attribute_taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $variation_attribute); // The taxonomy
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy ); // The WP_Term object
        // Searching for attribute 'pa_size' with value 'XL'
        if($attribute_taxonomy == $taxonomy && $term->name == $term_name ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $found )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Comment: Replace `$term->name` with `$term->slug`. In the function you linked, use `$term->name` because being a numeric value it doesn't matter which of the two you choose. Alternatively, you can use, without modifying the function, the attribute name as the value of the `$term_name` variable. Also the value of `$taxonomy` must always have the prefix **pa_** so in your case it must be **pa_production-time**.